# NoReverseMatch y Post Token en la URL en Class Based Views

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple *"editar y eliminar"* con las vistas basadas en clases de Django.

El problema es que estoy obteniendo estos errores con `UpdateView` y `DeleteView`. Uno ocurre cuando quiero redireccionar a su `DetailView` después de la actualización y el otro tiene lugar al pasar el token del formulario por la url y no me redirecciona a la página principal de la aplicación.

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import PinList, PinCreate, PinDetail, PinDelete, PinEdit

app_name = 'Pin'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', PinList.as_view(), name='pin_list'),
    url(r'^pin/add/$', PinCreate.as_view(), name='pin_add'),
    url(r'^pin/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PinDetail.as_view(), name='pin_detail'),
    url(r'^pin/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PinDelete.as_view(), name='pin_delete'),
    url(r'^pin/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PinEdit.as_view(), name='pin_edit'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, DetailView, DeleteView, UpdateView

from .models import Pin
from .forms import PinCreateForm

# Create your views here.
class PinList(ListView):
    model = Pin

class PinDetail(DetailView):
    model = Pin

class PinCreate(CreateView):
    model = Pin
    form_class = PinCreateForm
    template_name = 'pins/pin_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

class PinDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Pin
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Pin:pin_list')

class PinEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Pin
    form_class = PinCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Pin:pin_detail')
    template_name = 'pins/pin_edit.html'
```

**pin_detail.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <section class="Pin">
            <article class="Pin-container">
                <figure class="Pin-item"></figure>
                    <img src="{{ pin.image.url }}" alt="">
                    <figcaption class="Pin-user"> 
                        {{ pin.user.username}}
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href="{% url "Pin:pin_edit" pin.id %}">Edit</a>
                            <a href="{% url "Pin:pin_delete" pin.id %}">Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </article>
    </section>

{% endblock content %}
```

**pin_confirm_delete.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="POST" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are  you sure you want to delete {{ object.title }}?
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Después de confirmar, mi url cambia a:

> http://localhost:8000/pin/delete/7/POST?csrfmiddlewaretoken=nJB2q5by9VUio0JGOs1NVD4ES8VZ30DlZQ0og13jgTI7NM9EsDAWvnfxOK0iC4O5

Lo que ocasiona:

> *404 not found*

**pin_edit.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Add Pin</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Con éste, después de darle a enviar, me da el siguiente error:

> Reverse for 'pin_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pin/(?P\d+)/$']

Si alguien puede ayudarme con esto lo agradeceré.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error es sencillo, si te arroja un 404, es que la página no existe, y hay que ir a verificar que anda mal con las urls. En tu caso tienes el formulario en html de la siguiente forma:

```
<form action="POST" action="/">
```

Lo cual dice que envíe la información del formulario al endpoint `"POST"`, debes cambiarlo a:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
```

Que así especificas el método HTTP usado por el formulario.
Ahora, lo ideal es que si estas obteniendo ese formulario desde el GET de la vista que elimina, te recomendaría solo usar `action="."` de lo contrario cambiarlo a `action="/pin/delete/{{ object.id }}"` donde id es el id del pin.

Y para el segundo error, es algo que tienen las vistas basadas en clase, si tu le pasas una url, debes saber resolverla, por lo que te recomiendo sobreescribir el método `get_success_url` de la siguiente forma:

```
class PinEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Pin
    form_class = PinCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Pin:pin_detail')
    template_name = 'pins/pin_edit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('Pin:pin_detail', args=(self.object.id, ))
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta :)

Comment: Creo que nunca hubiese visto que no tenía el `method` en el formulario. Muchas gracias, todo esta resuelto. Ahora, con respecto al `success_url`, tal vez siempre haya que llamarlo como metodo o cual es su valor por defecto o en cual caso no necesitaria un sobreescribir ese metodo? 

Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @ikenshu su valor por defecto viene siendo lo que definas en `success_url` solo lo sobreescribo porque esa url necesita un parametro, el cual solo obtienes una vez inicializas la clase, de acuerdo a la url

Comment: Oh ya entiendo, es más que todo por el parametro! Creo que lo tengo claro ahora, muchas gracias!